# Why should I use the VPN?

Tags: passwords, network, windows, international, security-seal

Does a Virtual Private Network (VPN) provide an encrypted connection from outside networks or from ISPs to the internal network?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.  You are describing the broad reason why to use a VPN in your question's description itself.  What are you looking for?

Comment: the term VPN covers a broad range of technologies, that can connect specific hosts, or whole networks together.  The connection, may be encrypted, but can also be unencrypted.  So what you use it for, depends on what you want to use it for.  You configured to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a VPN because you want to protect whatever data you are sending over the network to your endpoint through encryption.

This sounds suspiciously like a homework question.